# Two columns in Revtex

Tags: enumerate, multicol, revtex

I am doing a list of problems for my students and I am using Revtex (the AIP template in ShareLaTeX). One of the problems has a lot of small items so I would like it to be in two columns (inside the two column environment).

My idea was to use `multicol` and then "enumerate". But `multicol` crashes with Revtex. What should I do?

Here's a little bit of the code: (I included all the packages I am using. Maybe it will be useful in the answer)

```
\documentclass[
aip,
jmp,
amsmath,amssymb,
reprint,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{\\}

\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{me}

\maketitle

\section*{Level 1}

\begin{problem}
Factor the following expressions:
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
      \item $a^2+b^2-9c^2-2ab$
      \item $a^8-b^2$
      \item $4x^4-9x^2+6x-1$
      \item $2ab+b^2+a^2-c^2$
      \item $a^2+12bc-4b^2-9c^2$
      \item $2xy-x^2-y^2+z^2$
      \item $-a^2+b^2-c^2+d^2+2ac+2bd$
      \item $a^4+a^2b^2+b^4$
      \item $a^4+a^2+1$
      \item $4b^4-37b^2c^2+9c^4$
      \item $16x^4-17x^2y^2+y^4$
      \item $64x^4+128x^2y^2+81y^4$
      \item $x^4-4a^2x^2+3a^4$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shall the numeration go downwards or from left to right, i.e. a) and b) in one row, then c).... and d)?

Comment: Downwards. a) is above b).

Comment: Your code produces an enumerated list across two balanced columns. If that's not what you want, please state what look you do want to obtain.

Comment: I want two columns of itens inside one major column.

Comment: Using `tasks` will do this simply, but the numbering will be horizontal.